# Get the ID of the each parent node while using Each Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can achieve to get the ID of the parent nodes in Each Loop. But the only problem is in my solution I am getting like this in console:

```
test-1       // test-1 id
     Test1
test-1       // test-1 id
     Test2
test-1       // test-1 id
     Test3

test-2       // test-2 id
     Test1
test-2       // test-1 id
     Test2

test-3
     Test1
```

My Expected Solution like is:

```
test-1        // test-1 id
     Test1
     Test2
     Test3

test-2       // test-2 id
     Test1
     Test2

test-3      // test-3 id
     Test1
```

Check My Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5muotp9n/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to rewrite your logic like this,

```
 $('#test .demo').each(function () {
       console.log(this.id);
     $("ul li", this).each(function(){
        console.log("   "+this.textContent)
     });
 });
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5muotp9n/3/)

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is to do a loop within a loop, so something like this:

```
$('#test ul').each(function () {

  var parents = $(this).parents('.demo').attr('id');
  console.log("Parent : " + parents);

  $(this).find('li').each(function(){ //for each li
    console.log($(this).html());
  });

 });
```

That should do the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('.demo').each(function () {

       var parents = $(this).attr('id');    
       console.log(parents);

       $(this).find("li").each(function(){
                console.log("    "+$(this).text());
     });

     });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5muotp9n/1/